# Select all entries from a table which are older then 3 days

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have this table in my database:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | name | model | inserted_time (timestamp) |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When I insert something into my table the **inserted_time** gets set automatically so this is the current timestamp.

---

Now I need to do a select on my table to get all entries which are 3 days older then the **inserted_time** timestamp. I'm doing this in PHP with **wpdb** in WordPress. This is what I already have:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM  my_table WHERE inserted_time /*OLDER THEN 3 DAYS */' );
```

---

For example when I've following entry in my table:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | name | model | inserted_time (timestamp) |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | James |  xxx  |    2018-11-14 21:20:04   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

---

So when I do my select now and the current timestamp is **2018-11-15 11:20:04** I don't want my entry in my results object / array (or what ever it is).

---

But when we have this current timestamp **2018-11-17 21:20:05** I need this in my results variable.

So I'm absolutely stumped with this. All my other stuff around this works fine, but this is still a problem.

Is it possible to do this only with SQL? Or do I need to pass a parameter like **$current_timestamp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `now()` or `current_timestamp`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  my_table
WHERE inserted_time < now() - interval 3 day;
```

Comment: select * from my_table where inserted_time < date_sub(now(), interval 3 day);

Comment: Never thought that it would be so easy. Thanks a lot sir.